# placing items at the beginning of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, selection

I got a select element, with multiple items. I'm supposed to place the values that start with '_' at the beginning of the list, ordered alphabetically. I tried doing it with the unshift() JavaScript method but it didn't work. is there any other way to do this?

html:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
<option>_c</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>_v</option>
<option>a</option>
</select>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var a = [];
$('option').each(function() {
    a.push($(this).text());
});
$('option').each(function() {
    var v = $(this).text();
    var s = v.substring(0,1);

    if (s == '_') {
        a.unshift($(this).text());
    }
});

a.sort();

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  $('option').eq(i).text(a[i]);
}
});
```

it outputs the following:

```
_c
_c
_v
_v
```

as you can see, it scrambles all values and losts reference to the ones without '_'.

Comment: what you expect is: -c -v a b ?

Comment: @brunozrk yes. _c _v a b

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. `a.sort()` will put `_` before letters.

Comment: The problem is that `a.unshift()` is removing elements from the array. Why are you using that?

Answer (score 2):

Alphabetically speaking, the underscore already has precedence over other characters, and will be automatically placed in front using a common `.sort()` method, so this would give you the correct order:

```js
var a = [];
$('option').each(function() {
  a.push($(this).text());
});
a = a.sort();

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  $('option').eq(i).text(a[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>_c</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>_v</option>
  <option>a</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

As discussed below, it may be *better* to re-order the elements, not just the values inside them. Also, there's room for improvement on the loops. So, here it goes a fancy way to solve your issue:

*OBS: JQuery's `.sort()` is not yet officially supported.*

```js
var select = $("select");
var opts = select.children("option");

select.append(opts.sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).text() > $(b).text();
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>_c</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>_v</option>
  <option>a</option>
</select>
```

Comment: IMHO, I think that's somewhat hacky.  It's shuffling the contents of the `option` elements, rather than shuffling the elements themselves.

Comment: @Alnitak - I totally agree. I didn't want to enter this matter though as it was not the point of the question, but a valid point obviously, and the OP should take it in consideration.

Comment: @Alnitak - Check a fancy way to do that on the updated answer!

Comment: Better, except: 1.  `.sort` isn't a supported jQuery function, 2. there's no need to `detach` - each node will be detached automatically when they're appended.

Answer (score 0):

Look the example http://jsfiddle.net/68t3x7hy/

```
var a = [];
$('option').each(function() {
    a.push($(this).text());
});

a.sort();
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  $('option').eq(i).text(a[i]);
}
```

As @Barmar said, .sort do the work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this plugin from this [blog article](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/), and so long as your options are all lower case:

```
jQuery.fn.mysort = function() {
    return this.pushStack( [].sort.apply( this, arguments ), []);
};
```

NB: although there's already a `$.fn.sort` method it's not supposed to be used outside of the library.

```
$('option').mysort(function(a, b) {
    var sa = $(a).text();
    var sb = $(b).text();
    return (sa < sb) ? -1 : (sa > sb) ? 1 : 0;
}).appendTo('select');
```

This extracts the `option` tags, sorts the elements by their contents, and then simply reappends them to the `select` element in the new order.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/L7ut14ok/

Answer (score 0):

Using `.map()`. As stated before, `.sort()` will do everything for your in this case.

```js
var a = $('option').map(function() {
  return this.outerHTML;
}).get().sort();

$('select').html(a.join(','))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>_c</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>_v</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>c</option>
  <option>_a</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a clean solution:

```
var $select = $('select');

$select.children().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML;
}).appendTo($select);
```

---

**UPDATE**

And if you don't want to use `$.fn.sort` (because it should be only used internally) you can do the following:

```
$($select.children().get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML;
})).appendTo($select);
```

[jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/h1cza7z6/1/)

Comment: That would indeed be very clean, if `.sort` was an officially supported method.  The source says that `$.fn.sort` is "internal use only".

Comment: The other issue is that your sort may not be deterministic since it only returns true or false (or "1" and "0" when converted back to numbers).  A correct sort function should also return -1 if `a < b`.

Answer (score 0):

For a more compact version of LcSalazar's answer:

```
var $o = $('option');
var a = $o.map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get().sort();
$o.text(function(n) { return a[n] } );
```

As with his answer, this has the potentially undesirable behaviour that it leaves the elements in place but shuffles their text values.